# Creating a dataframe with percents of disease per predicted chance in R with for loop

Tags: r, loops

I would like some help in creating a dataframe in R for per predicted chances.

I have a dataset of 156 patients, 39 without disease and 117 with disease and all patients have a predicted chance of disease (0,00-1). To determine a cut-off point I would like to create a dataset in which per increase of 1% chance the amount of with and without disease is shown.

So a dataset with 101 obs and 3 variables (percent chance, amount of patients with disease, amount of patients without disease)

I created the following loop, but it results in 287 observations.

```r
Valid2$disease_T <- Valid2$disease_present 
Valid2$disease_F <- ifelse(Valid2$disease_present == F, T, F)

plot2 <- data.frame()
for (i in 0:100) {
  per <- i
  amount <- Valid2 %>%
      select(disease_T, disease_F, predicted) %>%
      filter (predicted >= (i/100)) %>%
      count(disease_T, disease_F)
  plot2 <- rbind(plot2, per, amount)
}
```

dput of Valid2

```r
structure(list(disease_T = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), disease_F = c(FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), predicted = c(0.839047189743821, 
0.967837763160834, 0.786317285878715, 0.675276246104666, 0.989345368556793, 
0.555983868574255, 0.990942898545037, 0.811649758224556, 0.98426150620371, 
0.736827268936253, 0.979475139855437, 0.774123207779965, 0.957903428160418, 
0.91999882380089, 0.942305155149908, 0.991921678870239, 0.991594114313076, 
0.849292946424851, 0.97569066014882, 0.884909080808976, 0.979013574591358, 
0.998862491367365, 0.923394431637592, 0.885001406361028, 0.877973037376933, 
0.728550121991711, 0.999833278501221, 0.897790177969505, 0.979220428963593, 
0.999499362617635, 0.954494527800288, 0.961765702221913, 0.769280528680882, 
0.882613166009711, 0.986217524084092, 0.954192408993744, 0.872914657137128, 
0.531299550904597, 0.893933172484704, 0.480533848683641, 0.993094398777802, 
0.824802835501908, 0.947570508969646, 0.980540528086075, 0.583395480728772, 
0.822397774199589, 0.883912440796693, 0.594776303699779, 0.820790192098386, 
0.798073877022062, 0.985966496663131, 0.897069576653414, 0.831132493632043, 
0.852151002809375, 0.998435303514582, 0.953651187490499, 0.986591941625218, 
0.955233427577533, 0.683855028732251, 0.996623760378059, 0.899794970651676, 
0.89347885202678, 0.769929537527992, 0.795764657045519, 0.982146943465671, 
0.776440313355684, 0.914849623160958, 0.970905780657116, 0.500682448346073, 
0.863082837731646, 0.898528543977351, 0.961071059679792, 0.914764045084384, 
0.740320486660299, 0.558067744300918, 0.924289384162258, 0.640027164915262, 
0.991129364781095, 0.94097585658508, 0.948216610615068, 0.789283230550332, 
0.965724911188744, 0.992147113271609, 0.990048301774303, 0.929031670004039, 
0.909219568552839, 0.417005262010727, 0.954046684763806, 0.954662032660194, 
0.592707632714186, 0.71736673909297, 0.815939418957414, 0.530573198572189, 
0.411013385804287, 0.456143973275274, 0.98418041813448, 0.999743784673911, 
0.748231061596753, 0.957616694642036, 0.936005342173473, 0.990966443212461, 
0.998088129637225, 0.920524349831836, 0.995196908913598, 0.974348828931041, 
0.973717852722492, 0.938994862330677, 0.533156741117527, 0.990726457099523, 
0.513768273986449, 0.638444161218626, 0.858677012819686, 0.791287902868353, 
0.588849209133098, 0.44811826975699, 0.508084588253886, 0.530249454616573, 
0.488225901918474, 0.500562684131604, 0.317898539696961, 0.242177319047234, 
0.609587716312933, 0.539440893692799, 0.355494594307387, 0.266099968050094, 
0.723932395532802, 0.723938401792491, 0.53390474557177, 0.634097434175427, 
0.775172549607967, 0.570928462844033, 0.522356812838135, 0.724635429147149, 
0.610630883290112, 0.565371382980066, 0.285283409047343, 0.343302659495403, 
0.816510539572742, 0.656765409452827, 0.626301633190735, 0.383723283273525, 
0.594260652384327, 0.556639518107367, 0.418173506333977, 0.278806555045948, 
0.516264516564629, 0.292843578210485, 0.576288502786766, 0.408152351764115, 
0.650882387290395, 0.396480245419753, 0.834276346007703, 0.413110039326727, 
0.561240114285867, 0.387299107426737, 0.620969313796766)), row.names = c(NA, 
-156L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's difficult for us to help you without a "minimal, reproducible example" - we don't have `Valid2`. Can you create a sample dataset and share it with us? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#Providing%20a%20minimal%20dataset for how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Your count is returning two rows each:

```r
per <- 8
Valid2 %>%
  select(disease_T, disease_F, predicted) %>%
  filter (per >= (i/100)) %>%
  count(disease_T, disease_F)
# # A tibble: 2 x 3
#   disease_T disease_F     n
#   <lgl>     <lgl>     <int>
# 1 FALSE     TRUE         39
# 2 TRUE      FALSE       117
```

Further, I think your `per >= (i/100)

What I think you need is

```r
Valid2 %>%
  select(disease_T, disease_F, predicted) %>%
  dplyr::filter(predicted >= (per/100)) %>%
  summarize(percent = per, across(c(disease_T, disease_F), sum))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#   percent disease_T disease_F
#     <dbl>     <int>     <int>
# 1       4       117        39
```

But first, a quick public-service announcement:

> Iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). for each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Workarounds:

1. create an empty `out <- list()` and append the results to it each time, then after the loop run `bind_rows` on it:

   ```r
   plot2 <- list()
   for (per in 0:100) {
     amount <- Valid2 %>%
       select(disease_T, disease_F, predicted) %>%
       filter(predicted >= (per/100)) %>%
       summarize(percent = per, across(c(disease_T, disease_F), sum))
     plot2 <- c(plot2, list(amount))
   }
   plot2[1:2]
   # [[1]]
   # # A tibble: 1 x 3
   #   percent disease_T disease_F
   #     <int>     <int>     <int>
   # 1       0       117        39
   # [[2]]
   # # A tibble: 1 x 3
   #   percent disease_T disease_F
   #     <int>     <int>     <int>
   # 1       1       117        39
   plot2 <- bind_rows(plot2)
   tail(plot2, 3)
   # # A tibble: 6 x 3
   #   percent disease_T disease_F
   #     <int>     <int>     <int>
   # 1      98        25         0
   # 2      99        17         0
   # 3     100         0         0
   ```
2. use `lapply` wrapped in `bind_rows`,

   ```r
   plot2 <- lapply(0:100, function(per) {
     Valid2 %>%
       select(disease_T, disease_F, predicted) %>%
       dplyr::filter(predicted >= (per/100)) %>%
       summarize(percent = per, across(c(disease_T, disease_F), sum))
   })
   plot2 <- bind_rows(plot2)
   ```
3. Calculate it more simply:

   ```r
   newout <- Valid2 %>%
     mutate(percent = floor(100*predicted)) %>%
     group_by(percent) %>%
     summarize(across(c(disease_T, disease_F), sum)) %>%
     arrange(desc(percent)) %>%
     mutate(across(c(disease_T, disease_F), cumsum))
   head(newout, 3)
   # # A tibble: 3 x 3
   #   percent disease_T disease_F
   #     <dbl>     <int>     <int>
   # 1      99        17         0
   # 2      98        25         0
   # 3      97        32         0
   tail(newout, 3)
   # # A tibble: 3 x 3
   #   percent disease_T disease_F
   #     <dbl>     <int>     <int>
   # 1      27       117        37
   # 2      26       117        38
   # 3      24       117        39
   ```

   This has a property that if a percentage did not exist previously, it is not here, but we can easily fix that with:

   ```r
   newout2 <- full_join(newout, tibble(percent = 0:100), by = "percent") %>%
     arrange(percent) %>%
     tidyr::fill(disease_T, disease_F, .direction = "up") %>%
     mutate(across(c(disease_T, disease_F), ~ coalesce(., 0L)))
   head(newout2, 3)
   # # A tibble: 3 x 3
   #   percent disease_T disease_F
   #     <dbl>     <int>     <int>
   # 1       0       117        39
   # 2       1       117        39
   # 3       2       117        39
   tail(newout2, 3)
   # # A tibble: 3 x 3
   #   percent disease_T disease_F
   #     <dbl>     <int>     <int>
   # 1      98        25         0
   # 2      99        17         0
   # 3     100         0         0
   ```

   Which produces the same results as above:

   ```r
   all.equal(plot2, newout2)
   # [1] TRUE
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Note that you don't need to have both `disease_T` and `disease_F`

```
> (valid2$disease_T==!valid2$disease_F) %>% all
[1] TRUE
```

The below I think achieves what you're after.

```
percentages <- c(0:100)
valid3 <- valid2 %>% select(-disease_F) %>% # remove redundant column
                      mutate(roundedpercentage = ceiling(predicted*100)) %>% 
                      rename(disease = disease_T) #rename to just disease

nb_sick <- sapply(percentages, function(x) sum(valid3$disease[valid3$roundedpercentage<=x]))
nb_healhy <- sapply(percentages, function(x) sum(!valid3$disease[valid3$roundedpercentage<=x]))

result <- data.frame(percentages, nb_sick, nb_healhy)

> result
    percentages nb_sick nb_healhy
1             0       0         0
2             1       0         0
3             2       0         0
4             3       0         0
5             4       0         0
6             5       0         0
7             6       0         0
8             7       0         0
9             8       0         0
10            9       0         0
11           10       0         0
12           11       0         0
13           12       0         0
14           13       0         0
15           14       0         0
16           15       0         0
17           16       0         0
18           17       0         0
19           18       0         0
20           19       0         0
21           20       0         0
22           21       0         0
23           22       0         0
24           23       0         0
25           24       0         0
26           25       0         1
27           26       0         1
28           27       0         2
29           28       0         3
30           29       0         4
31           30       0         5
32           31       0         5
33           32       0         6
34           33       0         6
35           34       0         6
36           35       0         7
37           36       0         8
38           37       0         8
39           38       0         8
40           39       0        10
41           40       0        11
42           41       1        11
43           42       3        13
44           43       3        13
45           44       3        13
46           45       3        14
47           46       4        14
48           47       4        14
49           48       4        14
50           49       5        15
51           50       5        15
52           51       7        16
53           52       8        17
54           53       8        18
55           54      11        21
56           55      11        21
57           56      13        22
58           57      13        24
59           58      13        26
60           59      15        26
61           60      17        27
62           61      17        28
63           62      17        29
64           63      18        30
65           64      18        32
66           65      19        32
67           66      19        34
68           67      19        34
69           68      20        34
70           69      21        34
71           70      21        34
72           71      21        34
73           72      22        34
74           73      24        36
75           74      25        36
76           75      27        36
77           76      27        36
78           77      29        36
79           78      31        37
80           79      33        37
81           80      36        37
82           81      36        37
83           82      38        38
84           83      41        38
85           84      44        38
86           85      45        38
87           86      46        39
88           87      47        39
89           88      49        39
90           89      53        39
91           90      59        39
92           91      60        39
93           92      63        39
94           93      67        39
95           94      69        39
96           95      73        39
97           96      81        39
98           97      85        39
99           98      92        39
100          99     100        39
101         100     117        39

result$nb_sick %>% plot(t='l', col="red")
lines(result$nb_healhy, col="green")
```

[image]